# JQuery Span selector

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I am new in JQuery, and I try to show/hide span by clicking on checkbox.
I have span with id="spanId".
When I select it `$("span[id$='spanId']").toggle()` all works good , by I want to write more readable code and select span only by id , like this `$("#spanId").toggle();` but it doesn't work.

Anyone can explain why?

Comment: It should work if the span id is exactly `spanId`. The only difference between the first call is that in this cases it will match spans whose ids ends with `spanId`

Comment: **ID of an element must be unique** if you have multiple elements with the same ID fix it and then your selector `$("#spanId").toggle();` should be fine

Comment: Maybe you have more than one element with the same "spanId", so only the first element returns. check what '$("span[id$='spanId']").length' returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$("#spanId").toggle();` not working case probably id duplicate in HTML, if you want to target only span tag then try this code

```
$("span#spanId").toggle(); //span that have id spanId
```